# Best place for javascript additional code

Tags: php, javascript, html

My question is - is it ok to put javascript additional code (`<script>...</script>` tags containing simple things like validation etc - not linking to any external source) somewhere to the top inside of the `<body>` section ?

Is there any difference between placing it there and placing the code inside of the `<head>` section?

I want to create a layout file with one head section. Each templates will have different js parts of code - creating external links to .js files will disable the possibility of adding PHP tags, so I have to find another way.

Comment: "creating external links to .js files will disable the possibility of adding PHP tags" - Not so if you host the JavaScript files on your server, and configure your server to run .js files through PHP before serving them.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is it fine to put `script` tags in the `body` element, unless you have a good reason for putting it in `head`, it's *preferred* to put it in the `body` element, ideally just before the closing `</body>` tag. That way, your main content (your markup) is presented to the user as soon as possible rather than waiting for script files to load / the JavaScript engine to be fired up and execute the script.

References:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure library engineers on when DOM elements are ready for use](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

---

Side note on your comment:

> Each templates will have different js parts of code - creating external links to .js files will disable the possibility of adding PHP tags, so I have to find another way.

Ideally, try to find a way to make that just one file you load rather than a bunch of them. Each HTTP request has a significant amount of overhead. One of the recommendations you'll see in the first link above is to minimize the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: I place all my jquery at the very bottom of the page. I like to have all the markup at the top and all the script at the bottom. Easier for me to see what I want to see.

Comment: According to your edit - yeah, however, almost every file includes jquery, validation plugins, date widgets, and other things like that - it all makes quite a lot of http request, and I don't know if there's a way to minimize this...

Comment: Because it's mostly jquery - forgot to mention this, though eventually it's javascript :P

Answer (score 1):

In fact, having it at the top is less per formant and a risky place to put it:

Just before the closing body tag

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

> **Put Scripts at the Bottom**
>   tag: javascript
>   The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.
>   In some situations it's not easy to move scripts to the bottom. If, for example, the script uses document.write to insert part of the page's content, it can't be moved lower in the page. There might also be scoping issues. In many cases, there are ways to workaround these situations.
>   An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER attribute. In Internet Explorer, the script may be deferred, but not as much as desired. If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.

Comment: That doesn't really apply to the OP's situation though, as the OP is including JavaScript code directly in the `<script>` tags, rather than referencing JavaScript files to be downloaded. Granted, the browser will still pause rendering whilst the code is being *run* (I think), but unless it's some serious JavaScript, that shouldn't affect perceived performance.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the javascript code is included before you call it on your page, it shouldn't make a difference if it's in the head or in the upper section of the body.  It's a good idea to separate it if you're building a common header.  That way, you're not calling in unused code.